# TreeForm versus TreePlot conditional-tree-vertex-rendering

Tags: files-and-directories

According to TreeForm documentation "TreeForm takes the same options as TreePlot".
Now I tried to color TreeForm nodes differently.

The TreePlot example from questions/99586 is working...:

```
redDisks = {11, 23};
TreePlot[{11 -> 23, 11 -> 24, 23 -> 40}, 
VertexRenderingFunction ->({EdgeForm[Blue], If[MemberQ[redDisks, #2], Red, Green], Disk[#1, 0.2], Black, Text[#2, #1]} & )]
```

... but my TreeForm equivalent has no conditional coloring
and I have no idea, why:

```
nums = {2,10,20,80}; lownums = {2,10};
TreeForm[
  nums,
  VertexRenderingFunction -> ({EdgeForm[Blue], If[MemberQ[lownums, #2], Red, Green], Disk[#1, 0.2], Black, Text[#2, #1]}&)
]
```

Initially I intended to display a file tree, where directories should be nodes and files should be end nodes ("leaves"). Older files I wanted coloured differently:

```
fils=FileNames["*.nb"]; 
oldfiles = Select[fils,AbsoluteTime[Now]-AbsoluteTime[FileDate[#]]>86400&];
TreeForm[
  fils,
  VertexRenderingFunction -> ({EdgeForm[Blue], If[MemberQ[oldfiles, #2], Red,Green], Disk[#1, 0.2], Black, Text[#2, #1]}&)
]
```

There may also be a better method for such a FileTree? Thanks for any advice...

Answer (score 2):

If you  use `Text[InputForm @ #2, #1]` as the label you see that vertex names you want to refer to are wrapped with `HoldForm`.

```
nums = {2,10,20,80}; lownums = {2,10};

TreeForm[nums, 
 VertexRenderingFunction -> ({EdgeForm[Blue], 
     If[MemberQ[lownums, #2], Red, Green], Disk[#1, 0.2], Black, 
     Text[InputForm@#2, #1]} &)]
```

[image]

So you can do:

```
TreeForm[nums, 
 VertexRenderingFunction -> ({EdgeForm[Blue], 
     If[MemberQ[lownums, ReleaseHold @ #2], Red, Green], Disk[#1, 0.2], 
     Black, Text[#2, #1]} &)]
```

or

```
TreeForm[nums, 
 VertexRenderingFunction -> ({EdgeForm[Blue], 
     If[MemberQ[HoldForm /@ lownums, #2], Red, Green], Disk[#1, 0.2], 
     Black, Text[#2, #1]} &)]
```

to get

[image]

**Note:** Replace `Disk[#1, 0.2]` with `Disk[#1, Offset[20]]` to avoid distortion of disks:

[image]